# How can I merge 8-bit RGB tiff files using QGIS

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff

When I try to merge my tiff files without translating (converting format), my color space becomes grey.
If I try to translate my tiff, I am getting this error:
Error : band 1 has no color table

I want to retain my color space after merging.

This is the gdalinfo of one of tiff image:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: Muna_20160905_WV3_R2C1.tif
Size is 15957, 10018
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (13.160409776871793,11.860700450062284)
Pixel Size = (0.000003210135867,-0.000003210074723)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_COPYRIGHT=Image Copyright 2016 DigitalGlobe Inc
  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=1 (unitless)
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=1
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=1
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  13.1604098,  11.8607005) ( 13d 9'37.48"E, 11d51'38.52"N)
Lower Left  (  13.1604098,  11.8285419) ( 13d 9'37.48"E, 11d49'42.75"N)
Upper Right (  13.2116339,  11.8607005) ( 13d12'41.88"E, 11d51'38.52"N)
Lower Right (  13.2116339,  11.8285419) ( 13d12'41.88"E, 11d49'42.75"N)
Center      (  13.1860218,  11.8446212) ( 13d11' 9.68"E, 11d50'40.64"N)
Band 1 Block=512x512 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
Band 2 Block=512x512 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
Band 3 Block=512x512 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
```

If I perform identify, I get this:

```
Muna_20160905_WV3_R2C1.tif TIFF 15957x10018 15957x10018+0+0 8-bit sRGB 503.3MB 0.000u 0:00.010
```

The provider also tells in description:

These are "8-bit TIFs which ‘tiles’ the image"

Any help?

Comment: Are you sure they're 8 bit RGB (total 24bit)? It sounds like they're 8 bit pseudocolour images. Can you perform a GDALinfo on a couple and post the output please.

Comment: Add gdalinfo about one of the originals and from the merged image to your question.

Comment: I edited the question, please take a look now. @MichaelStimson

Comment: Tiled GeoTIFF is fairly normal, it makes for faster display at zoomed in display. When you say you're trying not to alter the format does that mean your output should be GeoTIFF but with all the images merged or are you trying to insert into an existing file without changing the raster extent?

Comment: I meant that my output should be GeoTIFF but with all the images merged.

Comment: The method I use is to create a VRT with GDAL (http://www.gdal.org/gdalbuildvrt.html) that is assuming the NoData value is set or the images have only valid values. You can use a VRT raster like a single raster but it only links to the images and does not convert them; you can build pyramids for the VRT to help your display rate when zoomed out. If you need a GeoTIFF mosaic use GDAL_Translate -of GTiff to convert the VRT referencing the existing images into one large mosaic... this works quite well and gives an opportunity to preview the mosaic *before* you commit to processing.

Comment: Problem is I don't know much about this GIS stuff.
By reading about VRT it seems like it is a virtual merged GDAL dataset.
I need combined tiff so that I can produce tiles later and I have information of pixels that corresponds to my shape file (labels) for ML purpose.

I don't think VRT can serve this purpose.

Comment: Are all your images similar? I would have a try by making a mosaic from two images which are for sure 8-bit RGB images like the image " Muna_20160905_WV3_R2C1.tif". The image `BROWSE.tif`feels suspicious by the name.

Comment: VRT should serve very well for your purpose and gdalbuildvrt is the tool I would recommend. You can materialize the virtual mosaic with gdal_translate as @Michael Stimson wrote. Gdalmerge.py is an older Python script but it may still suit better for some special cases.

Comment: Thanks, I'l see more about VRT. For now, can you please validate my answer? Browser.tif has same gdalinfo like other images.

Comment: After using this command:
gdalbuildvrt doq_index.vrt *.tif
I formed vrt file. Problem is I am getting several errors when I load this file in QGIS e.g. TIFFReadEncodedTile() failed, TIFFFillTile:Read error. 
On searching I found that these errors are some sort of bugs.
But, still this file opens but it is now really distorted when we zoom in.
Any help?

Comment: Last thing after translation, my new tif file has very low resolution.

Comment: Read the docs for GDALBuildVRT, use -resolution switch to make the coarsest resample. It sounds like you've got an overview raster in that folder forcing the resolution to become coarse. Distortion can come from projection difference, make sure you're viewing the file in its native spatial reference.